# Translate Curl's --key and --cert to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, curl, webservice-client

I need to post via VB.NET two files, a key file and a pem file, this can be done via Curl with the command:

```
curl https://someWebSite.com/test --key ./private_key.key --cert ./certificate.pem -d grant_type=password -d username="" -d password=""
```

So far I've done this in VB.NET but it just pops an error that says "`Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

i reached one example where they use a *.p12 file and i tried to recreate it in VB.NET but still saying the same error. This is my Code:

```
        Dim token As String = ""
    Dim uriVar As New Uri("https://someWebSite.com/test")
    Dim user As String = ""
    Dim password As String = ""



    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uriVar), HttpWebRequest)
    request.KeepAlive = False
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim credential As New NetworkCredential(user, password)
    request.Credentials = credential
    Dim keystoreFileName As String = "keystore.p12"
    Dim pathCert As String = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "cert\", keystoreFileName)
    Dim cert As New X509Certificate(pathCert, "allpassword")
    request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)


    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = 39
    request.Accept = "*/*"

    Dim requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Dim post_data As String = "grant_type=password&username=&password="
    Dim postBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data)
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) 'Here pops the error...
    Dim responseJson = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

    Return responseJson
```